# Conditional expectation $E\left[XY|X+Y=m\right]$ for independent normals

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am trying to find $E\left[XY|X+Y=m\right]$ where both X, Y are distributed as independent standard normals. I have tried two different approaches but I am not sure if anyone of them is correct. I am having more troubles than expected so it would be great if you could give me a hand.

First, I have tried solving:

$E\left[XY|X+Y=m\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(m-x) \; \frac{f_{x,y}(x, m-x)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f_{x,y}(x, m-x) dx }dx$

where $f_{x,y}(x, m-x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} exp \{ -\frac{x^2+(m-x)^2}{2} \}$

Second, I have thought that I could use the fact that:

$L\left[XY|X+Y=m\right]= E[XY] + \frac{Cov(XY,X+Y)}{Var(X+Y)}(m-0)$

However, I do not see why $E\left[XY|X+Y=m\right]$ should be linear.

Thanks.

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. standard normal then $$X=\frac12(X+Y)+Z\qquad Y=\frac12(X+Y)-Z$$ where $$Z=\frac12(X-Y)$$ is centered normal with variance $\frac12$ and independent of $X+Y$ hence $$XY=\frac14(X+Y)^2-Z^2$$ and $$E(XY\mid X+Y)=\frac14(X+Y)^2-E(Z^2)=\frac14(X+Y)^2-\frac12$$ thus, for every $m$, $$E(XY\mid X+Y=m)=\frac14m^2-\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks! So, for any $E[f(x,y)|g(x,y)]$ is the right approach to find a function h(.) such that f(x,y)=h(g(x,y),z) and then take the conditional expectation? Is there a systematic way to find this function h(.) or is it just a trial and error porocess?